# Plot with self defined x-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make a plot in gnuplot. My data files do not have an x-axis defined in them.

How can I define my own x axis with values "168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184" and pull the y values from a file.

I am using 
    Version 4.2 patchlevel 6 
    last modified Sep 2009
    System: Linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64

Comment: Why are you using a six year old version?

Comment: Ah. RHEL 6.6, i guess.

Answer (score 3):

Column "zero" gives the order of appearance of a data entry in the file (that is, the row number). You can use the `using` option offsetting your row number by 168 in your case, which is very simple since you increment the x value by a fixed amount (one):

```
plot "datafile" using ($0+168):1
```

If you need more flexibility defining your x values there is a number of more complicated options. In the most general case, you could have a string of values and you would choose the x value through a function which takes the order of the x value in the string as the argument:

```
xvalues="168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184"
f(i)=real(word(xvalues,i+1))
plot "datafile" using (f($0)):1
```

Comment: I get `internal error : non-INTGR argument` using the second option.

Comment: @paulolieuthier `f(i)` will only accept integers, a behavior inherited from `word()`. If you're passing a number with a decimal part it will likely raise an error.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. This works: `f(i) = real(word(xvalues, int(i) +1))`. Thanks again.